# Unit Testing and Coroutines in Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So i recently needed to implement some sequential code execution and with unity Coroutines seem to be talked about a lot to achieve this effect, and it did do the trick. However, it then broke all the unit tests i had for the logic. So to fix it i took out the logic from the function that has StartCoroutine called on it and then use reflection to call the method and it seems to do the trick. here is the code

```
    [Test]
    public void Teleport_ToEmptyOpenGrid( )
    {
        WCBattleCard bCard  = iMB.InstantiateObject<WCBattleCard>();
        GridSpace gSpaceOne = iMB.InstantiateObject<GridSpace>();
        GridSpace gSpaceTwo = iMB.InstantiateObject<GridSpace>();

        TestUtility.MockGridSpace(gSpaceOne);
        TestUtility.MockGridSpace(gSpaceTwo);

        gSpaceOne.rightSpace = gSpaceTwo;
        gSpaceTwo.leftSpace = gSpaceOne;

        bCard.ability = new WCUnstableTeleport(bCard,null);

        gSpaceOne.gridExtension.CardDroppedIntoGrid(bCard);

        Assert.IsNotNull(bCard.transform.parent);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(bCard.transform.parent.gameObject, gSpaceTwo.gridExtension.transform.gameObject);

        IOnTurnStart ability = bCard.ability as IOnTurnStart;

        Assert.IsNotNull(ability);

        TestUtility.ReflectMethod<WCUnstableTeleport> ("Teleport", null, (WCUnstableTeleport)bCard.ability, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        Assert.AreNotEqual(bCard.transform.parent.gameObject, gSpaceOne.gridExtension.transform.gameObject);

        TestUtility.ReflectMethod<WCUnstableTeleport> ("Teleport", null, (WCUnstableTeleport)bCard.ability, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        Assert.AreNotEqual(bCard.transform.parent.gameObject, gSpaceTwo.gridExtension.transform.gameObject);
    }
```

How it should be called is `StartCoroutine(ability.AbilityOnStart());` as all abilities implement that interface but unit tests don't seem to agree with that hence why i resorted to reflection, i also do not wish to expose the logic as public.

So my questions are

1. **Is this an acceptable way to do the tests?**
2. **If not what would they be?**

As a side question Is there an alternative to sequential operation other than coroutines that would make testing easier?

Comment: What "broke", it's not clear how coroutines break your tests.  You might also consider a better integrated (and free) [unit testing asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13802)

Comment: I am using that currently, but mostly in unit test form, hence why i am using the instantiateObject, it creates the object at its most basic...the best unity can do for mocking a game object